Wireguard clients can not KDE connect between peers
I succesfully established a Wireguard VPN from a Rocky Linux 9 server at the cloud. As of now there are two clients: a Fedora desktop and an Android mobile phone. The first problem I want to solve is to allow KDE Connect to see both clients which does not happen now.
The server config:
[root@vpn wireguard]# cat wg0.conf 
[Interface]
Address = 10.8.0.1/24
SaveConfig = true
PostUp = firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-masquerade
PostUp = firewall-cmd --direct --add-rule ipv4 filter FORWARD 0 -i wg -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
PostUp = firewall-cmd --direct --add-rule ipv4 nat POSTROUTING 0 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
PostDown = firewall-cmd --zone=public --remove-masquerade
PostDown = firewall-cmd --direct --remove-rule ipv4 filter FORWARD 0 -i wg -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
PostDown = firewall-cmd --direct --remove-rule ipv4 nat POSTROUTING 0 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
ListenPort = 51820
PrivateKey = server_private_key
[Peer]
# moto_g84
PublicKey = g84_pub_key
AllowedIPs = 10.8.0.6/32
[Peer]
# d3
PublicKey = desktop_pub_key
AllowedIPs = 10.8.0.7/32

[root@vpn wireguard]# cat /etc/sysctl.d/20-wireguard.conf 
# Port Forwarding for IPv4
net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
# Port forwarding for IPv6
net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding=1

Desktop config:
root@d3:/etc/wireguard# cat wg-client1.conf 
[Interface]
Address = 10.8.0.7/24
PrivateKey = desktop_private_key
PostUp = resolvectl dns %i 1.1.1.1 9.9.9.9; resolvectl domain %i ~.
PreDown = resolvectl revert %i
[Peer]
PublicKey = server_pub_key
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0
Endpoint = 1.2.3.4:51820
PersistentKeepalive = 25

Mobile config:
[root@vpn wireguard]# cat ~/moto_g84.wg 
[Interface]
Address = 10.8.0.6/24
PrivateKey = mobile_private_key
DNS = 1.1.1.1
[Peer]
PublicKey = server_pub_key
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0
Endpoint = 1.2.3.4:51820
PersistentKeepalive = 25

My home network is 192.168.15.0/24
I can ping from the desktop (static ip) to the mobile's home network address (dhcp) but a ping to the mobile's VPN address is filtered:
cpn@d3:~$ ping 192.168.15.4
PING 192.168.15.4 (192.168.15.4) 56(84) bytes de dados.
64 bytes de 192.168.15.4: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 tempo=140 ms
^C
--- 192.168.15.4 estatísticas de ping ---
1 pacotes transmitidos, 1 recebidos, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 140.194/140.194/140.194/0.000 ms
cpn@d3:~$ ping 10.8.0.6
PING 10.8.0.6 (10.8.0.6) 56(84) bytes de dados.
De 10.8.0.1 icmp_seq=1 Pacote filtrado
De 10.8.0.1 icmp_seq=2 Pacote filtrado
^C
--- 10.8.0.6 estatísticas de ping ---
2 pacotes transmitidos, 0 recebidos, +2 erros, 100% packet loss, time 1001ms

My guess is that the problem is at the firewall rules. How to fix it?

The masquerading breaks the clients' ability to address each other. You'll need to do without.
